# How to configure Hikari CP for HSQL in a Spring(4) context?

Tags: java, jdbc, hsqldb, spring-4, hikaricp

i want to use [Hikari CP](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP) in my Spring 4.0.3 context but seems i am missing something.

My bean configuration looks like:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource">
   <constructor-arg>
     <bean class="com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig">
       <constructor-arg>
         <props>
           <prop key="dataSource.driverClassName">${database.driver}</prop>
           <prop key="dataSource.jdbcUrl">${database.database.jdbc.url}</prop>
           <prop key="dataSource.port">${database.port}</prop>
           <prop key="dataSource.databaseName">${database.name}</prop>
           <prop key="dataSource.user">${database.user}</prop>
           <prop key="dataSource.password">${database.password}</prop>
         </props>
       </constructor-arg>

     </bean>
   </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

but i get an exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: one of either dataSource or dataSourceClassName must be specified
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig.validate(HikariConfig.java:655)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.<init>(HikariDataSource.java:66)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:148)
    ... 15 more
```

i have tried to configure dataSourceClassName using the HSQL [org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDataSource](http://hsqldb.org/doc/src/index.html?org/hsqldb/jdbc/JDBCDataSource.html)

that way:

```
<prop key="dataSourceClassName">org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDataSource</prop>
```

also that way:

```
<prop key="dataSource.ClassName">org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDataSource</prop>
```

both times i got the following exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.beans.IntrospectionException: Method not found: setPort
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.PropertyBeanSetter.setProperty(PropertyBeanSetter.java:109)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.PropertyBeanSetter.setTargetFromProperties(PropertyBeanSetter.java:61)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.initializeDataSource(HikariPool.java:497)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: java.beans.IntrospectionException: Method not found: setPort
    at java.beans.PropertyDescriptor.<init>(PropertyDescriptor.java:110)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.PropertyBeanSetter.setProperty(PropertyBeanSetter.java:97)
    ... 25 more
```

Can someone show me a working **Hikari CP Spring 4** bean configuration that **works with a HSQL DB**?

I am **not interested** in MySql, PG etc. because i know how to get them working. But i can't manage to get it done with HSQL.

Thanks,

Tech used: Java8, Spring 4.0.3, HSQL 2.3.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

one way to get the job done is to provide an instance of a DataSource object:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource">
  <constructor-arg>
    <bean class="com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig">
      <property name="dataSource">
        <bean class="org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDataSource">
          <property name="url" value="${database.database.jdbc.url}"/>
          <property name="databaseName" value="${database.name}"/>
          <property name="user" value="${database.user}"/>
          <property name="password" value="${database.password}"/>
        </bean>
      </property>
    </bean>
  </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

for sure there are other solutions.

HTH,

Comment: not sure what happens if you are duplicating the *databaseName* by using it along with a JDBC *url* (that already contains a database reference).

Answer (score 2):

Some of your properties in your example do not need the prefix 'dataSource' if you are using a driver-class.

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource">
   <constructor-arg>
     <bean class="com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig">
        <constructor-arg>
           <props>
              <prop key="driverClassName">${database.driver}</prop>
              <prop key="jdbcUrl">${database.database.jdbc.url}</prop>
              <prop key="username">${database.user}</prop>
              <prop key="password">${database.password}</prop>
          </props>
       </constructor-arg>
     </bean>
   </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

And `port` and `databaseName` can be included in the `jdbcUrl`.

Answer (score 2):

For a pure Java-config solution, I've used the following (in a class with a `@Configuration` annotation and included in the component-scan-path):

```
...
@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    return new HikariDataSource(hikariConfig());
}

private HikariConfig hikariConfig() {
    HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();
    config.setDriverClassName(driverClassName);
    config.setJdbcUrl(jdbcUrl);
    config.setUsername(username);
    config.setPassword(password);
    return config;
}
...
```

HTH

Comment: as i already mention, thats working fine, problem was in xml based configurations

Answer (score 1):

Tested under HikariCP 2.3.8 and Hibernate 4.3.8.Final:

```
<bean id="hikariConfig" class="com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig">
    <constructor-arg>
        <props>
            <prop key="dataSourceClassName">org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource</prop>
            <prop key="dataSource.user">${database.username}</prop>
            <prop key="dataSource.password">${database.password}</prop>
            <prop key="dataSource.databaseName">${database.databaseName}</prop>
            <prop key="dataSource.serverName">${database.serverName}</prop>
            <prop key="connectionTestQuery">SELECT 1</prop>
        </props>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource" class="com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource">
    <constructor-arg ref="hikariConfig" />
</bean>
```

For the *dataSourceClassName*, looks at the [popular datasource class names table](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP#popular-datasource-class-names).

*ConnectionTestQuery* is required for postgresql as per https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/issues/225, shouldn't be needed when using a latest jdbc driver version.