# java.sql.SQLTransientConnectionException: spring HikariCP - Connection is not available, request timed out afte

Tags: java, database, spring, hikaricp

I've catched java.sql.SQLTransientConnectionException: springHikariCP - Connection is not available, request timed out after 30001ms.

First code block works well, second (CP) does not work.

What is wrong and how fix this?

JDK - 1.8.0_73.

HikariCP - 2.4.5.

Spring - 4.2.5.RELEASE.

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
   <property name="driverClassName" value="${connection.driverClassName}"/>
   <property name="username" value="${connection.userName}"/>
   <property name="password" value="${connection.password}"/>
   <property name="url" value="${connection.url}"/>
    </bean>
```

CP

```
   <bean id="hikariConfiguration" class="com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig">
    <property name="poolName" value="springHikariCP"/>
    <property name="dataSourceClassName" value="${connection.dataSourceClassName}"/>
    <property name="maximumPoolSize" value="${connection.pool.maximumPoolSize}"/>
    <property name="idleTimeout" value="${connection.pool.idleTimeout}"/>
    <property name="dataSourceProperties">
   <props>
       <prop key="url">${connection.url}</prop>
       <prop key="user">${connection.userName}</prop>
       <prop key="password">${connection.password}</prop>
   </props>
  </property>
   </bean>
   <bean id="dataSource" class="com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource" destroy-  method="close">
  <constructor-arg ref="hikariConfiguration"/>
  </bean>
//...............
#CONNECTION
connection.dataSourceClassName=org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDataSource
connection.url=jdbc:hsqldb:mem:dbtest-local
connection.userName=sa
connection.password=

#POOL
connection.pool.maximumPoolSize=1
connection.pool.idleTimeout=28500

#HIBERNATE
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create-drop
hibernate.dialect=H2Dialect
hibernate.show_sql=true
```

Comment: In you HikariCP example you are setting the dataSourceClassName with the driverClassName. This may cause the problem?

Comment: Sorry, fixed. Mentioned problem is for proper CP property call - dataSourceClassName.

Comment: Does [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23369818/how-to-configure-hikari-cp-for-hsql-in-a-spring4-context) help?

Comment: I am checking now.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the dataSourceClassName, you should not provide the jdbc url.

Instead, you should add the host, dbname, etc. as properties. See the example on github:

```
dataSourceClassName=org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource
dataSource.user=test
dataSource.password=test
dataSource.databaseName=mydb
dataSource.portNumber=5432
dataSource.serverName=localhost
```

Otherwise, you should not use the dataSourceClassName. Try with:

```
<bean id="hikariConfiguration" class="com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig">
    <property name="poolName" value="springHikariCP" />
    <property name="maximumPoolSize" value="${connection.pool.maximumPoolSize}" />
    <property name="idleTimeout" value="${connection.pool.idleTimeout}" />
    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${connection.url}" />
    <property name="dataSourceProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="user">${connection.userName}</prop>
            <prop key="password">${connection.password}</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

This is working for me in local.

Comment: No property portNumber for HSQL - exception. Without this property - same result - timeout.

Comment: I edited my answer for an alternate way without dataSourceClassName, tell me if this works better

Comment: I think something is wrong on the part we cannot see, because I have been able to run a test project with this configuration

Comment: Yes with hsqldb 2.3.3